# [Go]: govips: undefined: vips.Startup

Tags: go, libvips

I am trying to use govips in my project, but can't get it to work.

I even tried to create an empty project with just two files:

`main.go`

```
package main

import "github.com/davidbyttow/govips/v2/vips"

func main() {
    vips.Startup(nil)
    defer vips.Shutdown()
}
```

`go.mod`

```
module test

go 1.21.4

require github.com/davidbyttow/govips/v2 v2.13.0

require (
    golang.org/x/image v0.14.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/net v0.18.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/text v0.14.0 // indirect
)
```

But got the same errors:

```
undefined: vips.Startup compiler UndeclaredImportedName
undefined: vips.Shutdown compiler UndeclaredImportedName
```

The only things that exposed are:

[image]

Comment: It could be that this is just an IDE issue, have you tried restarting/reconfiguring/upgrading your IDE? And to confirm whether or not this is an IDE problem, you can try building the code using the `go build` command, if that succeeds then you know it's the IDE and not Go itself.

Comment: @mkopriva my bad, I should've mentioned that this errors occurs at build step as well